# Compare two NSStrings and check for spelling mistakes or missing letters

Tags: nsstring, uitextfield, compare, spell-checking

I would like to compare two strings, one which the user enters into a UITextField and another which I have stored (I know how to do this).

However I would like to notify the user if they have misspelt the string they have entered compared to the stored string, could anyone shed some light on how to do this comparison.

Answer (score 0):

The **Identifying and Comparing Strings** section of the [NSString Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003744) provides methods exactly for that. Please check.

I believe in your case, the following methods would be helpful,

1) `isEqualToString:` example, `[string1 isEqualToString:string2]` returns *YES* if the strings are same, else *NO*

2) `caseInsensitiveCompare:` example [string1 `caseInsensitiveCompare:string2]` compares the strings, regardless of its case. Returns an `NSComparisonResult`. If it is `NSOrderedSame`, then the strings match, else they dont.

3) `compare:options:` example `[string1 compare:string2 options:NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch]` compares the strings, with `options` to compare such as an `NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch` where the search treats characters such as 'ö' and 'o' as same, `NSNumericSearch` where the numbers within the string are compared using numeric values and so on. (Refer the **Search and Comparison Options** of the NSString Class Reference)